# Let $\lim _{n\to \infty }a_n = L$ and $[a_n]$ diverge prove that $L \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $\lim _{n\to \infty }a_n = L$ and $\lfloor a_n \rfloor $ diverge prove that $L
>  \in \mathbb{Z}$
>
> and find the Partial  limits of $\lfloor a_n \rfloor $

for : 
$a_n=\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{n}$

for this sequence the limit is $0 \in \mathbb{Z} $ and for $\lfloor a_n \rfloor$ the sequence be ${\{-1,0,-1,0,-1,....}\}$ so $\lfloor a_n \rfloor$ diverge and the Partial  limits are $-1,0$

but this is example not a proof any idea how i can prove this ?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If $L$ is not an  integer then there exits an integer $k$ such that $k <L<k+1$ Since $a_n \to L$ we must have $k <a_n <k+1$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Hence $[a_n]=k \to k$.